# jquery scrollTop with 'slow' animation jumps before start when html's scroll-behaviour is smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone, smooth-scrolling

When I use `slow` or `1000` as a duration a jump occurs before the scrolling and then the scroll happens. How can I fix this? I want to control the duration when `html scroll-behaviour` is smooth.

```js
$('.scroll-btn').click(function(e) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".scrolled-div").offset().top + (-104)
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the site: https://nordic.dnscheck.io/

Comment: I created a snippet for you from the JS and CSS you included in the question. Please edit this to include the HTML necessary to create a working example.

Comment: What's `.scroll-btn` (more specifically, what's the *HTML* for the button/div)?  Does it do it if you use a longer duration?  Shorter duration?  Is the page already scrolled? at the top?

Comment: scroll-btn is the caret button. when it pressed I want to scroll to `scrolled-div` div.
It works If I give 0-10 as duration. but when I give longer duration it jumps before starts.

Comment: For me, with a guess at the html, with `scroll-behaviour:smooth` - it seems to *wait* for the animation timeout, then run its own scroll after that timeout: https://jsfiddle.net/rc3ygnvw/  change animation time to 0  - don't see a "jump" though.

Comment: can you please check it on your phone? Does it lag? my client complains that it is kind of choppy on his iphone.  that's why I am trying different solutions. I mean on the live site